# Is the spectral radius subadditive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius

If $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian matrices, then

$$r(A + B) \leq r(A) + r(B)$$

where $r$ denotes the spectral radius. Are there other standard conditions when this is true?

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B$ are normal we have
$r(A) = \lVert A \rVert$ and $r(B) = \lVert B \rVert$. Because in general we have 
$$
r(A+B) \leq \lVert A+B \rVert,
$$
then $r(A+B) \leq r(A) + r(B)$ must hold.